# Level DB data store gets recreated everytime

Tags: node.js, leveldb

I am new to web app development, and still learning the basics. I am working on a basic application with nodejs and level db. Every time I restart my web application, the leveldb data store gets recreated, and the data that was stored in it is all gone.

My example code is below:

```
var level = require ('level');
var db = level('./mydb.db', {createIfMissing : true});
```

My understanding is that the db will get created only if it is missing.. otherwise the existing db would be used. In my case that is not happening.. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try the absolute path to the db while opening, it is possible the relative path is changing each time server runs.